# ¿Como resolver jquery.js:4 POST (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy creando una pagina que obtiene datos desde una base de datos el problema es que me sale este error: jquery.js:4 POST 500 (Internal Server Error
Esta es la función js:

```
function info(p){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'idCliente': p},
    url: 'getInfoProductos.php',
    success:function(r){
      console.log(r);
      datos = $.parseJSON(r);
      $('#nombreSelec').val(datos[0]['nombre']);
      $('#precioSelec').val(datos[0]['precio']);
      $('#caracSelec').val(datos[0]['descripcion']);

    }
  });

}
```

Y este es el código php que llama a la función que hace la consulta sql:

```
<?php
require_once('./conexion.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $obj=new Conexion();
    $datos=$obj->select($_POST['idCliente']);
    echo json_encode($datos);
}else{
    header('location: ../index.html');
}


 ?>
```

No se cual sea el problema

Comment: no veo que enviar la variable `$_POST['idCliente']` en el js, solo envias el id

Comment: había puesto otro código, ya esta el correcto

Comment: revisa la conexión con la base de datos, ya que el error 500 se debe a un error del servidor, no de JavaScript, posiblemente la conexión no se este realizando correctamente o también la consulta que se realiza

Comment: ¿El método `select` de la clase `Conexion` puede recibir solo un parámetro, generar una consulta a la base de datos y devolver las filas correspondientes?

Comment: Ayudaría mucho saques del log el error que se generó para saber exactamente que pasa

Comment: primero que nada no hagas caso a los comentarios que te dicen aquí; ni siquiera saben si tu tienes acceso a la configuración de tu servidor/entorno; lo primero que te recomendaría es que te documentes sobre que es un error 500 del servidor y donde buscar el error cuando obtienes un error de esa clase. lo que si te puedo decir es que el error esta en tu código php puede o no puede ser el que has mostrado.